# How do I select specified radio button of each group

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
 <fieldset class="target-radios">
        <legend>Date Range</legend>
        <div>
          <input id="dateUnspecified" type="radio" name="muScheduleDateRange" value="0" selected-item="0">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="dateAll" type="radio" name="muScheduleDateRange" value="1" selected-item="0">
        </div>
        <div class="from-to">
          <input type="radio" id="dateFromTo" name="muScheduleDateRange" value="2" selected-item="0">
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

How do I select specified radio button(selected-item) by looping through each group? Ideal loop should only work once per group.

Tried this approach but doesn't work & loops through each group multiple times:

```
$('#targeting input:radio').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name'),
    selected = $(this).attr('selected-item');

    if(typeof selected !== 'undefined') {
        $('input[name='+ name +']:nth-child('+ selected +')').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by specified?

Comment: What did you expect that attempt to *do* if it had been successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember elements are 0 indexed, so subtract 1.

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name'),
        aselected = parseInt($(this).attr('selected-item'), 10) - 1;
    if (typeof aselected !== 'undefined') {
        $('input[type="radio"][name="' + name + '"]').eq(aselected).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

NOTE: you displayed no target but to add that change:

```
$('#targeting').find('input[type=radio]').each...
```

EDIT re: updated markup: remove the -1 on the `aselector` index calculation

```
$('.target-radios').find('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name'),
        aselected = parseInt($(this).attr('selected-item'), 10);
    var me = 'input[type="radio"][name="' + name + '"]';
    if (typeof aselected !== 'undefined') {
        $(me).eq(aselected).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, it's selecting wrong(3rd) button with updated markup, any clue?

Comment: @RuntimeException - I added an example with the -1 removed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure of what you meant, but you might try something similar to this,

```
$('div').each(function () {
    // Determine the selected item id
    var selectedItemId = $(this).eq(0).attr('selected-item');

    // Check it
    $(this).find('input[value="' + selectedItemId + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Also, you could give your divs the same class like "*group*", so you can use `$('.group').each()` instead.

Comment: I want to select 2nd radio button in group 1 and 3rd in 2nd. Simple!

Comment: @RuntimeException I think I just understood what you want. I've updated my code, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to make up your own attributes. I substituted `data-selected-item` for your `selected-item`

```
$('div').each(function () {
    $('input', this).eq($(this).find('input').data('selected-item') - 1).prop('checked', true);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Nr6YF/1)**

Update:

You can try this variation based on your change:

```
$('input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('selected-item') == (parseInt($(this).val(), 10))) $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Nr6YF/2/)**

Comment: Works great, however I have got an issue with my html structure, could you please make this work without div?

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with current structure? Thanks for help.

Comment: It would really help if you didn't keep changing your HTML. Now in this latest example, what would be repeated? The fieldset block or the divs within the fieldset?

Comment: Apologies for changing HTML. fieldset block will be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/5xg3h/2/)

Try this, I have added the `targeting` div,

```
$('#targeting div').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).children(0).attr('name');
    var selected = $(this).children(0).attr('selected-item'); 
    if(typeof selected !== 'undefined') {
        $('input[name='+ name +']:nth-child('+ selected +')').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps,thank you

Comment: I have added another answer ,check it out, I think it meets your requirement

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/kzXwy/)**

Here it is

This will get the radio with distinct `'name'`attribute, so the loop will be executed depending up on number of distinct groups ie `'name'`attribute

```
var divs = $('input').map(function () {
     return this.name
 }).get();
 var uniqueName = $.unique(divs);
 for( i=0 ; i<uniqueName.length;i++)
 {
var selected = $("input[name="+uniqueName[i]+"").attr('selected-item'); 
$('input[name='+ uniqueName[i] +']').eq(selected).attr('checked', true);
 }
```

Hope this helps,Thank you